# How to identify overlapping filter conditions as rows in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The example below is an output from an optimization that produces a list of values that I will use as filters, and apply to another set of data.

I am trying to eliminate rows that produce values/filters that are already covered in the other rows, leaving only unique values/filters.
For example, if I apply the values/filters in index row #1 (var_1 > 2, var_1< 5,var_2 >5, var_2 <9), it would produce the same result as the value/filters in index row 0 (1,5,5,9)

Index rows #0, #2, and #3 should be unique_result = True

In attempt #1, my code is simply looking whether the value is <= to a min or >= to a max, but as you can see, record #1 comes out as True since the fourth value 9 is greater than or equal to the max.

In attempt #2, I am filtering the dataframe to first remove the row that I am iterating through, then see if the value is less than the minimum of the filtered dataframe's min.  (I only did this for one value, as I am getting NaNs that I don't understand).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "var_1_lower_limit": [1, 2, 1, 3, 2],
        "var_1_upper_limit": [5, 5, 4, 7, 6],
        "var_2_lower_limit": [5, 5, 3, 6, 4],
        "var_2_upper_limit": [9, 9, 8, 9, 7],
    }
)


def find_unique(
    var_1_lower_limit, var_1_upper_limit, var_2_lower_limit, var_2_upper_limit
):
    if (
        var_1_lower_limit <= df_filtered.var_1_lower_limit.min()
        or var_1_upper_limit >= df_filtered.var_1_upper_limit.max()
        or var_2_lower_limit <= df_filtered.var_2_lower_limit.min()
        or var_2_upper_limit >= df_filtered.var_2_upper_limit.max()
    ):
        return True
    else:
        return False


### Attempt #1
df["unique_result"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: find_unique(
        x["var_1_lower_limit"],
        x["var_1_upper_limit"],
        x["var_2_lower_limit"],
        x["var_2_upper_limit"],
    ),
    axis=1,
)

display(df)

### Attempt #2
for i in df.itertuples():
    df_filtered = df.drop(df[df.index == i.Index].index)
    df["low_value_2"] = df_filtered.var_1_lower_limit.apply(
        lambda x: True if x < i.var_1_lower_limit else False
    )

display(df)
```

Edit: added output of what I'd hope to end up with
[image]

Comment: can you provide desired output as text table?

Comment: Hi, in the expected output, can you explain why line 4 is false?

Comment: @ Laurent because the results of filtering on record 4 would all be captured by records 0, 2, or 3, so record 4 doesn't add anything new.  If var_1 is 2, 3, 4, 5, it would pass based on record 0 as well.  if var_1 = 6, it would pass based on record 3.  if var_2 was 4, 5, 6, or 7, it would pass based on record 2.

Comment: @ Laurent - Ileaving my comment above, because after I typed this, I realized you were right.  If var_1 = 5 and var_2 = 4, it would pass the filter only based on record 4.  Maybe my solution is iterating through all possibilities of var_1 and var_2 (values 1 through 9), and creating a column of "pass_or_fail", and then seeing if there is a combination of var_1 and var_2 which only creates one value of 'Pass' in pass_or_fail, and that is how I would identify if a filter is unique...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks again to @Laurent who pointed out a combination I was overlooking, so rather than trying to compare if the filters were a min or max, I realized I needed to iterate through all possible combinations of potential values.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np


### On two variables
df = pd.DataFrame({'var_1_lower_limit':[1,2,1,3,2],'var_1_upper_limit':[5,5,4,7,6],'var_2_lower_limit':[5,5,3,6,4],'var_2_upper_limit':[9,9,8,9,7]})
df.sort_values(['var_1_lower_limit','var_1_upper_limit','var_2_lower_limit','var_2_upper_limit'],ascending=True, inplace=True) # I think important to sort here
display(df)


default_possibilities = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
possibilities = list(itertools.product(default_possibilities,default_possibilities,default_possibilities,default_possibilities)) #Creates all combinations of possibilities 0-9,0-9,0-9,0-9
print('length of possibilities',len(possibilities))
possibilities = [item for item in possibilities if item[1]>=item[0] and item[3]>=item[2]] # removes combinations that don't make sense such as first value is 5 and second value is 3
print('length of revised possibilities',len(possibilities))

filtering_output = []

# For each combination of potential values, see if it passes a filter
for i in possibilities: 
  a = i[0]
  b = i[1]
  c = i[2]
  d = i[3]
  for z in df.itertuples():
    if z.var_1_lower_limit <=a and z.var_1_upper_limit >=b and z.var_2_lower_limit <=c and z.var_2_upper_limit >=d:
      filtering_output.append({'combination':i,'filter_id':str(z.var_1_lower_limit)+','+str(z.var_1_upper_limit)+','+str(z.var_2_lower_limit)+','+str(z.var_2_upper_limit),'var_1_lower_limit':z.var_1_lower_limit,'var_1_upper_limit':z.var_1_upper_limit, 'var_2_lower_limit':z.var_2_lower_limit,'var_2_upper_limit':z.var_2_upper_limit,'pass_or_fail':'YES'})
    else:
      continue

filtering_output_df = pd.DataFrame(filtering_output) ### This df has all passing combinations
display(filtering_output_df)  

unique_combinations = filtering_output_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['combination'], keep='first') # Since there are combinations that pass multiple filters, reduce to only the first iteration of that combination

final_filters = unique_combinations.drop_duplicates(subset=['var_1_lower_limit','var_1_upper_limit','var_2_lower_limit','var_2_upper_limit'], keep='first') # since df was sorted, keeping only filters that had a passing combination
display(final_filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idiomatic way to do it with Pandas [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sort dataframe and set 'unique' column with 'True' as default value
df = df.sort_values(
    by=[
        "var_1_lower_limit",
        "var_1_upper_limit",
        "var_2_lower_limit",
        "var_2_upper_limit",
    ]
).assign(unique=True)

# Identify filters not contained within others by comparing current row
# with previous one or the next, and set them as 'False'
non_unique_filters = (
    (df["var_1_lower_limit"] >= df["var_1_lower_limit"].shift(-1))
    & (df["var_1_upper_limit"] <= df["var_1_upper_limit"].shift(-1))
    & (df["var_2_lower_limit"] >= df["var_2_lower_limit"].shift(-1))
    & (df["var_2_upper_limit"] <= df["var_2_upper_limit"].shift(-1))
) | (
    (df["var_1_lower_limit"] >= df["var_1_lower_limit"].shift(1))
    & (df["var_1_upper_limit"] <= df["var_1_upper_limit"].shift(1))
    & (df["var_2_lower_limit"] >= df["var_2_lower_limit"].shift(1))
    & (df["var_2_upper_limit"] <= df["var_2_upper_limit"].shift(1))
)
df.loc[non_unique_filters, "unique"] = False

df = df.sort_index()
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
   var_1_lower_limit  var_1_upper_limit  var_2_lower_limit  var_2_upper_limit  unique
0                  1                  5                  5                  9    True
1                  2                  5                  5                  9   False
2                  1                  4                  3                  8    True
3                  3                  7                  6                  9    True
4                  2                  6                  4                  7    True
```